# use numpy.ndarray in matplotlib title plot with format

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-xarray

I am using Sara and matplotlib of some of work and I was wondering how could I use a class numpy.ndarray with specific format in the title of a plot I am doing.

The variable type is:

```
type(global_mean.data)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

and value:

```
global_mean.data
array(0.12485412, dtype=float32)
```

And I would to be in the title of the plot as:

Mean = 0.12

I tried something like this:

```
plt.title('Mean= ' + str(global_mean.data), fontsize=5, loc='right')
```

But it is not working.

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: I mean to say xarray instead of Sara :P

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean?

Comment: You can, and should, fix typos using the [edit] button below your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(20)

plt.plot(arr)

plt.title(f'Mean =  {"{:.2f}".format(arr.mean())}')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The way how is declared the plt.title works. But what about the format of the number: In my case I did something like this - plt.title(f'Max= %1.2f {global_mean.data}', fontsize=5, loc='right')  . But in the title the number is not formatted. Thanks

Comment: updated for formatting check above

Answer (score 0):

You can get a scalar from a single-element array using the `item` method:

```
plt.title(f'Mean = {global_mean.data.item()}', fontsize=5, loc='right')
```

This will work for a scalar array, a `(1,)` array, a `(1, 1)` array, etc. You can also index into a scalar array with `()`:

```
plt.title(f'Mean = {global_mean.data[()]}', fontsize=5, loc='right')
```